# Call a procedure when there is change in data of view/table in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a snowflake stored procedure that should be executed when there is a change in data in snowflake view/table.

I tried creating a Stream called mystream that points to a table.

```
create or replace stream mystream on table TEST1;
```

And created a Task as

```
    CREATE or replace TASK mytask1
  WAREHOUSE = TEST_WH
  SCHEDULE = '1 minute'
WHEN
  SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('MYSTREAM')
AS
  CAll sp_test_proc('ABC')
```

However, the stored procedure didn't execute even after SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('MYSTREAM') returned TRUE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you check the status of the task?

```
show tasks;
```

I suspect you haven't resumed it.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html#usage-notes

If it's resumed, then use the TASK_HISTORY function to check the ERROR_MESSAGE of the latest execution. You may also check the query ID.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/task_history.html